# Have no combined "Android SDK and AVD manager" for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-adt, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to follow the "Hello World" at the Android Developer site, but am stuck on a step where it asks me to open up the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" in Eclipse - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#avd

I gather that what I'm meant to be seeing is a combined Android SDK and AVD manager, like this one: http://developer.android.com/images/sdk_manager_packages.png

However, I don't seem to have that. From what I've read I should be able to get to it by opening up "SDK Manager.exe" in the SDK root. But that just gives me a single SDK Manager window, not the combined one. Without the combined one obviously the "Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager" option in Eclipse is out of the question.

So how can I get the combined Android SDK and AVD Manager window to show? Are these separate windows a feature of the newest SDK package? Help!

Comment: these are features since r14.

Comment: Oh blah, never mind. I updated and restarted Eclipse and now there are two window options: 'Android SDK Manager' and 'AVD Manager'. Seems the new SDK has separated these two.

Answer (score 1):

These functions have been separated into 2 applications (windows) since SDK 14. To finish that part of the tutorial use the AVD Manager and follow the instructions, from memory this window should be almost identical to the original SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse "Window -> Android SDK Manager" and "Window -> AVD Manager" . It is easy to find. Since a lot of versions of SDK updated , you must update your environment.